# ng-click function in angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-factory

I would like to change a variable in a angularjs (1.x) factory with a click event. After that the pause button should appear. Could you please help me:

The link with ng-click:

```
<li ng-click='navPlayMusic()'>
  <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-play music-control"></a>
</li>
<li ng-show="musicControl.playTitle === true" ng-click='navPauseMusic()'>
  <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause music-control"></a>
</li>
```

**EDIT:**

The controller:

```
music.controller('musicController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, musicControl) {
  ...
  $scope.musicControl = musicControl;
  $scope.navPlayMusic = function() {
     musicControl.playMusic();
  }
  ...
});
```

The factory:

```
music.factory('musicControl', function () {
return {
  playTitle: false,
};
this.playMusic = function() {
  return {
    playTitle: true
  };
 };
});
```

Comment: You don't appear to be injecting your `musicControl` factory into your controller

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your answer. Now I injected musicControl into the controller but it still not work.

Comment: Change the factory to return the `playMusic` function. Clients of a factory can only access properties of the object returned. Properties of the `this` object are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Factory:

```
    music.factory('musicControl', function() {
        var _flags = {  //Note: we intentionally declare properties here for easy to track how many flag we have in factory (optional)
            playTitle: false 
        }
        return {
            flags: _flags,
            playMusic: playMusic
        };

        function playMusic(dummyParam) {
            //handle play music logic
            //dummyParam will be 5 if called from HTML.

            //after done, enable the flag
            _flags.playTitle = true;
        };
    });
```

Controller:

```
    music.controller('musicController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, musicControl) {

        //...

        $scope.musicFlags = musicControl.flags;   //map only property that we need to use. More than that is just make code hard to understand
        $scope.navPlayMusic = musicControl.playMusic; //just need to map function

        //...

    });
```

HTML:

```
    <li ng-click='navPlayMusic()'>
        <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-play music-control"></a>
    </li>
    <li ng-show="musicFlags.playTitle === true" ng-click='navPauseMusic(5)'>
        <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause music-control"></a>
    </li>
```

Comment: This works. Thank you very much. Learned a lot with this answer.

Comment: One more question: How can I add parameters to the functions and give them from the html code to the factory?

Comment: Hi, you can just set param in HTML as normal. I edited code. basically, in controller, you set navPlayMusic to the reference of playMusic which mean when you call navPlayMusic, you actually call playMusic and pass param to it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the reference of the factory function in the return object

```
music.factory('musicControl', function () {
return {
  playTitle: false,
  playMusic : playMusic 
};
function playMusic () {
  return {
    playTitle: true
  };
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //try this
 music.factory('musicControl', function () {
 return {
    playTitle: false,
    playMusic : function() {
       return {
         playTitle: true
       };
     }; 
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..

Factory:

```
music.factory('musicControl', function() {

        var playTitle = false;
        function playMusic() {
            return playTitle = true;

        }

        return {
            playMusic: playMusic
        }
    });
```

controller:

```
$scope.isPause = false;
$scope.navPlayMusic = function() {
    $scope.isPause = $scope.musicControl.playMusic();
}
```

HTML :

```
<li ng-click='navPlayMusic()'>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-play music-control"></a>
</li>
<li ng-show="isPause === true" ng-click='navPauseMusic()'>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause music-control"></a>
</li>
```